# Как отключить все эффекты в том числе и прозрачность в picom?

Tags: linux, blur

Как отключить все эффекты в том числе и прозрачность и размытие в picom?

[мой picom.conf](https://gist.github.com/akimdi/f703ac7704b322218a1f1a583ac7e4aa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

оказывается нужно было просто добавить опцию [no-fading-openclose = true](https://gist.github.com/akimdi/f703ac7704b322218a1f1a583ac7e4aa#file-picom-conf-L91)